# Is it worth having SATA 6GB/s cables?

Tags: hard-drive, ssd, sata

I've just received some SATA 3 6GB/s cables that I ordered last week, and it struck me how ordinary they look when compared to normal standard SATA cables.

My PCI-E SATA3 card is yet to arrive.

My question is, would a standard SATA cable have the same transfer speeds as my SATA 3 6GB/s cables?
Question is similar to [this one](https://superuser.com/questions/712355/is-there-a-difference-between-different-sata-cables), but however it doesn't have an answer.

*This question isn't asking 'are all SATA cables compatible with SATA 3', it's asking whether SATA 2 and SATA 3 transfer speeds are the same.*

Comment: Alternatively, please mark in comments in future WHERE the answer is in the supposed duplicate; I just found the answer, but you never marked it as such.

Comment: The answer to the duplicate question DOES answer your question.  The cables are the exact same.  That by definition means that they will work at the speeds the protocol defines (i.e. SATA 2 drives/ports will transfer at SATA 2 speeds, and SATA 3 at SATA 3 speeds).  The cable doesn't matter.

Comment: @BBlake What I meant was that the moderator should have pointed out the correct answer, since there are a few answers on that question.

Comment: As with all questions on any StackExchange site, the accepted answer (if there is one) is marked.  The question that is linked to yours as duplicate has an answer voted up 11 times and marked with a green checkmark (meaning this is the answer accepted by the person asking the original question).  This is more than sufficient to indicate a correct and valid answer.

Comment: @BBlake Yes, but this *accepted answer* did not answer my question, rather it was the one below it that answered my question.